# Where is my Happiness?

Tags: stellaris

I can't seem to find an indicator anywhere for how happy my empire is! I see modifiers every now and then, but nothing about the actual happiness. I have checked everywhere, nothing in steam forums other than how to increase it, nothing on the wiki that I can see, nothing!

I would assume there isn't a happiness rating and not to worry about it, but every now and then I see something that modifies it such as an increase by 5% or that robots are always 100% happy.

Is happiness actually calculated in the game? If so, how do I find out what my empire happiness is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out not long after posting the question.

Happiness is calculated in the game and it is a per 'pop' basis. This means each section on a planetary grid that is occupied by a population unit, or 'pop', has it's own individual happiness level. It is on a percentage scale.

The indicator looks like a progress bar right below the portrait of the pop icon, it is the same indicator that is used as a progress bar when a pop is being grown there. It's on a color scale, looks like the happier one is the greener it is and the unhappier one is the yellow to red it gets.

Comment: This does seem to be the only place it's listed. It would be real nice if there was a planet-wide, sector-wide, and/or empire-wide average displayed somewhere.

Comment: Happy is green. Blue is when the pop is growing / under construction (for robots)

Comment: It's also kinda blue when it's around 70% happiness

Comment: @TaylorAllred Do you have a screenshot? Because both Happy (71-89) and Joyful(90+) look the same shade of green to me.

Comment: Not at the moment, I'll see if I can get it tonight. Maybe I'm misremembering

Comment: @DCShannon Except happiness really is calculated per population.  A single planet can have pops of varying happiness due to different factions, races, and genetics.  I'm not sure that an average of 72% would be helpful, if it really means all your loyalists are 95%, but all your xeno's are 20%

Comment: @RavenDreamer you are right about the colors, I made an edit.

Comment: @Kexlox It would be very helpful if all my colonies have ~70% happiness, except for one with ~50% because then I would know to go look at it, where I could see that most people were fine but a few separatists were stirring things up.